# Insert current date into a date column using Microsoft Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to write a query that when executed writes todays date in the appropriate column? I am using Microsoft Access Query Designer.

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO TestingDates ( DateColumn )
VALUES (GetDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use intrinsic Date() function.

`INSERT INTO TestingDates(DateColumn) VALUES(Date());`

Comment: What if I need to enter a date 30 days from today?

Comment: Is there anyway I can do Date() + 30 or plus one month?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to do this?

Comment: You can do exactly that: `Date() + 30` because day is default unit. If you want to add other units (such as month or year), use DateAdd() function. You should do some research on date manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

yes; in the calculated field for the date; try just
TestingDate: Date()+30

I think it is that simple

Answer (score 0):

In what context are you running the SQL statement? You can use the function you wrote if you are using the QueryDef Object in VBA.

```
    Private Sub Test_Update_SQL()
        Update_SQL1 "Test_Query", "Test_Table"
    End Sub
    Public Function Update_SQL(Query_Name As String, Table_Name As String)
    Dim Obj_Qdef As Object
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
        Set Obj_Qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(Query_Name)
        'Debug.Print Generate_Query_String(Table_Name) 'For troubleshooting SQL
        Obj_Qdef.SQL = Generate_Query_String(Table_Name)
        CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
        Obj_Qdef.Execute
        Set Obj_Qdef = Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function Generate_Query_String(Table_Name As String) As String
        Generate_Query_String = "INSERT INTO " & Table_Name & "( DateColumn )VALUES (#" & Get_Date() & "#);"

    End Function

    Private Function Get_Date() As String
        Dim Temp_Date As Date
        Dim Temp_Date_Plus As String
        Temp_Date = DateAdd("d", Now(), 30)
        Temp_Date_Plus = Format(Temp_Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Get_Date = Temp_Date_Plus
    End Function
```

A few Notes to remember whenever you use update or insert queries always enclose date values in # # and strings in ' ' for vba I like to use chr(35) = # [pound/hashtag] and chr(39) = ' [single quote] when writing code that will generate SQL.